# Singular matrix with entries in a ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, determinant

Given a matrix $M\in A^{n\times n}$, where $A$ is a commutative ring different from $\{0\}$, then we know that if there exists a vector $x\in A^n$ such that $Mx=0$, then $\det M$ must be a zero divisor.

The converse is true? That is, if $\det M$ is a divisor of zero, is it true that his kernel is non-trivial? And if $\det M=0$?

The only thing I obtained is that it's true for Principal Ideal Domains, thanks to the Smith Form.

Comment: For any domain (PIDs included), the only zero divisor is zero.

Comment: I'm not sure if this holds for arbitrary commutative rings, but if it does, then it should be useful: $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I$, where adj denotes the [adjugate matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, it does: you can prove the formula in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\{x_{ij}:1\le i\le n,1\le j\le n\})$, observe that you do everything in $\mathbb{Z}[\{x_{ij}:1\le i\le n,1\le j\le n\}]$ and then specialize it to any commutative ring.

Comment: @egreg excelent! Good to know.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom See, for a slightly different argument, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/799322/62967

Answer (score 0):

The below is incorrect as of now, but might help someone give a correct proof.  Feel free to modify it.

---

If $\det(M)$ is a zero divisor, we have the following: let $a \in A$ be such that $a\det(M) = 0$, and take $x = (a,0,\dots,0)^T$.  We have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
M[\adj(M)x] = [\det(M)\adj(M)] x = \det(M) Ix = 0
$$
Thus, if $\det(M)$ is a zero divisor, the kernel of $M$ is indeed necessarily non-trivial.

Comment: not quite: who tells you that $adj(M)x\ne 0$?

Comment: You should prove that $\operatorname{adj}(M)x\ne0$.

Comment: We know that $\det (M)I$ is non-zero, so $\adj(M)$ can't be zero. So, if it's $j$th column is non-zero, put $a$ in the $j$th entry.

Comment: Let $M=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ be such that $Mb=0$ for some $b\ne0$ and that $\det(M)\ne0$; note that $\det(M)b=0$. Then for $x=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}b\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ you have $\operatorname{adj}(M)x=0$.

Comment: @egreg perhaps that complicates things...