# Are adjugates of similar matrices similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true in general, that if $A \sim B$, i.e. $\exists C: A =C^{-1}BC$, then $\mathrm{adj}(A) \sim \mathrm{adj}(B)$? It's quite obvious if the matrices in question are invertible (that is, $\det A \neq 0,\ \det B \neq 0$); if they are not, however, it's not as easy. I couldn't prove nor disprove this fact – could someone here do this?

Answer (score -2):

We need the identities $adj(MN)=adj(N)adj(M)$ and $adj(M)=\det(M)M^{-1}$. See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties) for a proof. See the [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799284/operatornameadjab-operatornameadj-b-operatornameadj-a) in this site for another source. So we have \begin{align}adj(A)&=adj(C^{-1}BC)\\&=adj(BC)adj(C^{-1})\\&=adj(C)adj(B)adj(C^{-1})\\&=C^{-1}adj(B)C\end{align}So $adj(A)$ similar to $ adj(B)$.

Comment: That's obviously not a valid proof. For two reasons, even. a) How do you define $A^{-1}$, if $\det A = 0$? And if it is not 0, as I said, the proof is easy. b) I'm not talking about matrices being _equal_ --- I'm talking about _similar_ matrices (and I even defined the term in my question)

Comment: see the updated one.

Comment: I don't think you can actually prove that $\mathrm{adj}(MN)=\mathrm{adj}(N)\mathrm{adj}(M)$ ( * ) using the fact that $\mathrm{adj}(M)=\det(M)M^{-1}$, but that's okay; I seem to recall that it is valid. Anyway, yeah, now it's nice and correct, I can't beleive I didn't see that. I'll accept a bit later --- maybe ( * ) is not correct and someone will disprove it.

Comment: Well, yeah, I thought about this for a bit, but I can't find a simple proof for the first identity; therefore, your answer is not complete (yet?)

Comment: @Akiiino see the updated answer. I have included the wiki link for the proof you are looking for.

Comment: Wiki has the same invalid proof; I don't think that the fact that it's THE WIKI makes wrong things right.

Comment: @Akiiino Ok, sorry. Now I see your point. This proof is incomplete in its current form.

Comment: @Akiiino Can you check the proof for the identity you are looking for in the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799284/operatornameadjab-operatornameadj-b-operatornameadj-a . I am not able to grasp it.