# Doubts regarding adjoint of matrices

Tags: matrices

Adj(AB) = Adj(B) . Adj(A)

For non-singular matrices we know that B$^{-1}$ . A$^{-1}$ = (AB)$^{-1}$ . This implies $\frac{Adj(B)}{|B|}$ . $ \frac{Adj(A)}{|A|} $ = $\frac{Adj(AB)}{|AB|} $.

We know |AB| = |A| |B|

But i don't know how to prove it for singular matrices.Is the law valid in case of singular matrices?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799284/operatornameadjab-operatornameadj-b-operatornameadj-a?rq=1

Comment: But i know how to do for non - singular matrices @Brian Moehring.

Comment: The [currently top] answer given by egreg works for any $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ with entries in a field.  The next answer given by Evan works for any $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ with entries in a commutative ring.  Neither assumes the matrices are non-singular.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably here $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
The two sides are continuous functions (in fact polynomials) in the entries of $A$ and $B$.
Since it's true for the nonsingular matrices, which are a dense set, it must also be true for the singular matrices.

Comment: I want a proof that does not uses that fact .