# Linear algebra: det calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two square $3 \times 3$ real matrices $A$ and $B$ verifying
$$\det( B \cdot \operatorname{adj} A) = 8 \qquad \text{and} \qquad  \det(A \cdot \operatorname{adj} B)=1.$$
where $\operatorname{adj} M$ is the adjuguate matrix associated to $M$ (eq $\operatorname{adj} M = {}^t\!\operatorname{comat} M$).

My goal is to compute $\det(AB)$, it is supposed to be easy, and I got 8, but the answer in the book is 2. How am I wrong?

---

I multiplied the two given det, then I united them since $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$ and then used the formula $M \cdot \operatorname{adj} M = \det M \cdot I$ and I got $\det(AB)=8$.

Comment: Please type your equations, and don't post them as pictures. Have a look at the [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: How did you get 8? What were your steps?

Comment: Use that $ A\cdot \text{adj} A = \det (A) I$.

Comment: @DominikS it's the adjugate matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: @ADDD use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516127

Comment: @CyclotomicField i did and i got 8, i multiplied the 2 given det, then i united them since det(AB)=detA*detB and then used what you mintioned

Comment: Mind $\det(kI_3)=k^3,$ not $k.$

Comment: @AnneBauval oops, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Beware also, in the solution you sketched, to write correctly the [adjugate matrix of a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799284) (the order is reversed, I don't know if it occured to you).

Answer (score 0):

Take a square matrix $M$ of size $n \times n$, then you have:
$$M \cdot \operatorname{adj} M = \det M \cdot I_n  $$

Thus you have
$$\begin{align*}
\det (AB)^3 &= \det (A)^3 \det (B)^3 = \det (\det A \cdot I_3) \cdot \det(\det B \cdot I_3) \\
&= \det(A  \operatorname{adj} A) \cdot \det(B \operatorname{adj} B) = \det(A) \det(\operatorname{adj} A) \det(B) \det(\operatorname{adj} B)\\
&= \det (B \operatorname{adj} A) \det(A \operatorname{adj} B) = 8
\end{align*}$$

Thus $\det(AB) = 2$.

Fun fact: necessarily, $\det A = 4$ and $\det B = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You found correctly
$$\begin{align}8&=\det(B\operatorname{adj}A)\det(A\operatorname{adj}B)\\
&=\det A\det B\det(\operatorname{adj} B)\det(\operatorname{adj} A)\\
&=\det(AB\operatorname{adj}(AB))\\
&=\det(\det(AB)I_3).
\end{align}$$
So, your conclusion should be
$$8=(\det(AB))^3\text{ i.e. }\det(AB)=2.$$